# orderby function giving exception as "at least one object must implement icomparable" when i have a List<> in another List<>

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a Classes like this:

```
Public class ClassA
{

public Class1[] Class1{ get; set; }

}

Public class Class1
{

public Class2[] Class2{ get; set; }
public double TotalTime1 { get; set; }

}

Public class Class2
{

public double Count{ get; set; }

}
```

here i am trying to sort the ClassA like below:

```
IList<Class1> Data = new List<Class1>();
Data = ClassA.Class1.OrderBy(m => m.Class2.OrderBy(k => k.Count)).ToList();
```

Please how can i sort the Class1 using the Count in Class2.

Comment: There are *multiple* `Class2` values per `Class1` value though - how do you expect to use them to compare two `Class1` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to sort on the result of the inner `OrderBy`, which is a sequence of `Class2` objects and this doesn't implement `IComparable`.

You have to sort on a single value, not a sequence. If you for example want to sort on the largest `Count` value in each `Class1` object, use the `Max` method:

```
IList<Class1> Data =
  ClassA.Class1.OrderBy(m => m.Class2.Max(k => k.Count)).ToList();
```

There are also other plausible ways that you may want to produce a value from the `Class2` array, like for example using the `Min`, `Sum`, `Average` or `First` method.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler and LINQ do not know how either `Class1` or `Class2` should be ordered - how are objects of these types compare to each other.

You need these classes to implement [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) and [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) so these kinds of objects can be compared with each other - these interfaces are used for ordering.